# NoClassDefFoundError can't get data from azure table

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to read data from an azure table using the below code in an android project.

```
        TableQuery<Observation> rangeQuery =
                TableQuery.from(Observation.class)
                        .where(combinedFilter);

        Iterable<Observation> results = cloudTable.execute(rangeQuery);
        // Loop through the results, displaying information about the entity

        for (Observation entity : results) {
            res.add(entity);
        }
```

As soon as I try to enumerate `results` it throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory` exception.

A table entity looks like this:

```
{"PartitionKey":"temperature",
"RowKey":"2014-12-19 23:15:19",
"Timestamp":"2014-12-19T23:15:20.2638537Z",
"humidity":38.0,
"temp":22.0,
"datetime":"2014-12-19 23:15:19"}
```

And the corresponding class is:

```
public class Observation extends TableServiceEntity {

    String temp;
    String humidity;
    String datetime;
    String PartitionKey;
    String RowKey;
    String Timestamp;
}
```

I suspect this is a serialization error. But I can't see anything wrong since all the properties are implemented in the Observation class.

Comment: Can you try converting type of `humidity` and `temp` to `Double` or equivalent in your class?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the Azure SDK doesn't install one of its dependency. It can be downloaded from: [jackson-core](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.5.0/)

Comment: If you're using Android Studio/Gradle that will install the dependency automatically. Unfortunately through Eclipse there isn't as clear a system to use.

Comment: I used Gradle with Android studio. Still had to install it manually. :\

Comment: Hmmm, how did you include the storage library in your project and what version of Android Studio are you on? If you take a look at the [Gradle build file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-android/blob/master/microsoft-azure-storage/build.gradle) it includes the Jackson dependency.